# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SharedStylesHost' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm having a really hard time updating an Angular 2 project to Angular 4. I'm following the steps in https://update.angular.io/. Things seems to work however when I run the APP I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SharedStylesHost' of undefined in vendor.js file.

when I run the following command `npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@^4.1.0 typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'`

I then run this command `npx webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` which builds the vendor.js file

I already tried, deleting the node_modules directory and package-lock files and then do npm install but does not work.

Here is my package.json file

```
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.20.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^0.3.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^0.15.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.29.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.16.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.18.7",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.21.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^0.16.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.3.6",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.12.11",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.6",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.0-beta.13 || ^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json file

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

webpack.config.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = true; //!(env && env.prod);
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map';
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin(), new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/')
        )]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                //filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

and my webpack.config.vendor.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/compiler',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/router',
                '@angular/platform-server',
                'angular2-universal',
                'angular2-universal-polyfills',
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'es6-shim',
                'es6-promise',
                'event-source-polyfill',
                'jquery',
                'zone.js',
                '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css'
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: 'css-loader' }) }
                ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{ test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] }],

        },
        entry: { vendor: ['aspnet-prerendering'] },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

Comment: You post your entire project, do you think anyone will read your question, be specific!

Comment: how specific, I don't know why I'm getting this error. The project builds fine in Visual Studio 2017 however, when I run(start debuging) I get the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SharedStylesHost' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js?```